# Conversion of java.util.Date to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

In our codebase I've run into this code converting current timestamp into `OffsetDateTime`:

```java
public static OffsetDateTime getUTCTime(){
    Date date = new Date();
    // Convert Date object to UTC OffsetDateTime object
    Instant instant = date.toInstant();
    return instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

I wonder whether it is possible to replace this code with this:

```java
public static OffsetDateTime getUTCTime(){
    return OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

Will the returned value be equivalent for both snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference in accuracy.

In your first code snippet you provide new Date() which uses currentTimeMillis().
When converted into an OffsetDateTime, it can only show up to milliseconds.

> Example: "2024-02-02T14:09:04.042Z"

Your second code snippet directly uses the OffsetDateTime object, which is nano second accurate.

> Example: "2024-02-02T14:09:04.042471300Z"

Maybe there is a requirement to "only" show/persist the millisecond or if persisted as a string the first one would obviously need less space. As Holger notes in a comment, you can simply use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)` to get rid of anything smaller than milliseconds.

Apart from that, I can't tell you if one of them is more efficient.

Comment: Of course, you can simply use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)` to get rid of anything smaller than milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR;

It should return similar value in most cases, but precision might be different.
OffsetDateTime converted from Date could only represent up to millisecond, where `OffsetDateTime.now` could represent up to nanosecond.

It may sounds okay at first, but as per my personal experience, this could lead to different issues, like:

- When doing comparison, some test could fail because of higher precision.
- The value before saving to database could be different to the value retrieved after saving to database, due to inconsistent precision.
- The formatted datetime, toString() may looks different
  e.g.
  2024-02-02T13:47:18.838Z vs
  2024-02-02T13:47:18.838890Z

---

### Why are they different?

From [documentation of Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html),

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Obviously, the precision of OffsetDateTime converted from Date is limited to millisecond.

And if we check the source code of `OffsetDateTime.now`,

```java
public static OffsetDateTime now(ZoneId zone) {
    return now(Clock.system(zone));
}
```

```java
public static OffsetDateTime now(Clock clock) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(clock, "clock");
    final Instant now = clock.instant();  // called once
    return ofInstant(now, clock.getZone().getRules().getOffset(now));
}
```

We can see the instant is retrieved from `Clock.system(zone)`, by referring to [Clock documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html).

> The system factory methods provide clocks based on the best available system clock. This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), or a higher resolution clock if one is available.

Hence it could have higher precision, if available.

Comment: Thanks, I vote +1. For the case we don't need precision higher than minute, so the substitution seems correct

Comment: Also, since it's TL;DR :) — it worth to mention that additionally to precision, usually, there are small side effects in performance as well (depends on platform as well).

On my Mac it's about:
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
MyBenchmark.getUTCTime_newDate_bench  thrpt   25  20858265.331 ± 333934.769  ops/s
MyBenchmark.getUTCTime_now_bench  thrpt   25   8519944.904 ± 142734.588  ops/s